# SQL for updating a field from a matching field in another table

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I am trying to populate a field in a table using data from another table which is acting as a lookup table, something like this but it doesn't appear to work seems to run indefinitely suggests welcome.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
  SET field=(select field2
               FROM table2 t2
               WHERE t1.otherfield=t2.otherfield)
```

Comment: What does "seems to run indefinitely" mean? More context is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the merge statement can be more efficient in some cases. You can try the following also :-

```
merge into table1 t1
using(select otherfield,field2 from table2)y
on(t1.otherfield=y.otherfield)
when matched then
update set field=y.field2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.field=t2.field2 
FROM Table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 On t1.otherfield=t2.otherfield
```

Is the trick you want.